# How to secure my PHP site using sessions?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I am trying to understand a good method to secure my site from being attacked. I am currently using cookies method. However, after some web research, I find that cookies are not good to be used for security reasons. So my other option would be to use sessions.

I read this article [Sessions and security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php). In the reply by Anurag Jain he states that the site should use https and not http so that the session id won't get sniffed.

But there's a few things that I don't understand.

When a user logs in the site. I will run a query to check if the credential match the username and password. Then I would store some information into different sessions (ie. USER_ID, FULL_USER_NAME, TEAM_NAME, ACCESS_LEVEL)

After logging in and a session is created then I can create session_id() after the session starts. After that I can save the session in a database table along with the IP address. but after this how would I do the security check every time to ensure that this user is the one who really created the session and not a hacker?

How can this secure the site, "if the session id is compromised can't the attacker use that to log in if she/she was able to replicate the same IP address? Also how can this work if I want many users to user it from the same office "same network - same external IP address"?

One article that I gained lots of info from was [How to Create a  bulletproof sessions](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions).

Comment: Because their `$_SESSSION['whatever']` would match your database table row column. Of course you should use `https`, and I would use `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` if you're using MySQL.

Comment: @PHPglue, can you please be more specific and explain more? what is $_SESSION['whatever'] ?can't the $_SESSION['whatever'] be compromised? Yes I am using MySQL 5.6.13 so I can use the function you listed.

Comment: The whole question sounds as if you have not really understood what sessions _are_ at all so far.

Comment: At the very top of your PHP page it's: `session_start();`. Then let's say that you randomly generate a PHP `sha1(String)` that you throw into a database. When your user logs in, you really check for their username and password. Then you get this value from your database and assign it like: `$_SESSION['arbitrary_name'] = 'mysqli->query result Object property here';`. Now on your other web pages you query your database: `if(isset($_SESSION['arbitrary_name']) && $_SESSION['arbitrary_name'] === 'mysqli->query result Object property'){/*execute more queries to grab data that's user specific*/}`

Comment: SSL is a good idea, as it makes eavesdropping attacks so hard as to be nearly impossible (you probably don't need to worry about ISPs doing this, but you should with public wifi and cafe wifi operators, who are generally a lot less accountable). That said, a site protecting golf scores probably does not need to be concerned about this in the same way as a bank. Thus, it depends a great deal on what you are protecting.